# How to trigger animation when element is in view?

Tags: javascript, html, css, animation

so I want to trigger the animation of the `skill-bars` when the element itself is in view on the website. For example, when the user scrolls down the section where the element is, then the animation should take place.

I got the idea and everything working but there is some problem I am facing which I cannot seem to figure out, what I did essentially (with the help of codepen), is that I added a `js` file that triggers the animation when the element is in view and included `animate` in my `CSS` file so that it adds that class whenever the element is in view. However, the problem is that since there is not just one animation the `CSS` file includes as almost every class in `CSS` has some animation attached to it, so how would I include all the animation of the element in one class called `animate`?

Code:

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) { 

// get the element to animate
var element = document.getElementById('box');
//var elementHeight = element.clientHeight; //For some reason, stackoverflow produces an error for this line

// listen for scroll event and call animate function
document.addEventListener('scroll', animate);

// check if element is in view
function inView() {
  // get window height
  var windowHeight = window.innerHeight;
  // get number of pixels that the document is scrolled
  var scrollY = window.scrollY || window.pageYOffset;
  
  // get current scroll position (distance from the top of the page to the bottom of the current viewport)
  var scrollPosition = scrollY + windowHeight;
  // get element position (distance from the top of the page to the bottom of the element)
  var elementPosition = element.getBoundingClientRect().top + scrollY + elementHeight;
  
  // is scroll position greater than element position? (is element in view?)
  if (scrollPosition > elementPosition) {
    return true;
  }
  
  return false;
}

// animate element when it is in view
function animate() {
  // is element in view?
  if (inView()) {
      // element is in view, add class to element
      element.classList.add('animate');
  }
}
});
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:wght@200;300;400;500;600;700&display=swap');
*{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
}
body20{
  height: 100%;
  place-items: center;
  background: transparent;
}
::selection{
  color: #fff;
  background: black;
}
.skill-bars{
  padding: 25px 30px;
  width: 97%;
  background: #fff;
  box-shadow: 5px 5px 20px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  border-radius: 10px;
}
.skill-bars .bar{
  margin: 20px 0;
}
.skill-bars .bar:first-child{
  margin-top: 0px;
}
.skill-bars .bar .info{
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}
.skill-bars .bar .info span18{
  font-weight: 500;
  font-size: 17px;
  opacity: 0;
  animation: showText 0.5s 1s linear forwards;
}
.animate{ /* This is the animation class */

}
@keyframes showText {
  100%{
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
.skill-bars .bar .progress-line{
  height: 10px;
  width: 100%;
  background: #f0f0f0;
  position: relative;
  transform: scaleX(0);
  transform-origin: left;
  border-radius: 10px;
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.05),
              0 1px rgba(255,255,255,0.8);
                animation: animate 1s cubic-bezier(1,0,0.5,1) forwards; 

}
@keyframes animate {
  100%{
    transform: scaleX(1);
  }
}

.bar .progress-line span18{
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  border-radius: 10px;
  transform: scaleX(0);
  transform-origin: left;
  background: black;
  animation: animate 1s 1s cubic-bezier(1,0,0.5,1) forwards;
}
.bar .progress-line.html span18{
  width: 84%;
}
.bar .progress-line.css span18{
  width: 76%;
}
.bar .progress-line.jquery span18{
  width: 91%;
}
.bar .progress-line.python span18{
  width: 59%;
}
.bar .progress-line.mysql span18{
  width: 70%;
}
.progress-line span18::before{
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  top: -10px;
  right: 0;
  height: 0;
  width: 0;
  border: 7px solid transparent;
  border-bottom-width: 0px;
  border-right-width: 0px;
  border-top-color: #000;
  opacity: 0;
  animation: showText2 0.5s 1.5s linear forwards;
}
.progress-line span18::after{
  position: absolute;
  top: -28px;
  right: 0;
  font-weight: 500;
  background: #000;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 1px 8px;
  font-size: 12px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  opacity: 0;
  animation: showText2 0.5s 1.5s linear forwards;
}
@keyframes showText2 {
  100%{
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
.progress-line.html span18::after{
  content: "84%";
}
.progress-line.css span18::after{
  content: "76%";
}
.progress-line.jquery span18::after{
  content: "91%";
}
.progress-line.python span18::after{
  content: "59%";
}
.progress-line.mysql span18::after{
  content: "70%";
}
```

```html
 <section>
        <div class="container" data-aos="fade-up">
      <div class="section-title">
        <h2>What I am Working On</h2>
        </div>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/picturealign.css"> 
      <div class="column1">
      <div class="row1">
  <div class="skill-bars">
    <div class="bar">
      <div class="info">
        <span18>Harvard CS50 Course</span18>
      </div>
      <div class="progress-line html">
        <span18></span18>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="bar">
      <div class="info">
        <span18>Youtube Channel (Java Tutorials)</span18>
      </div>
      <div class="progress-line css">
        <span18></span18>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="bar">
      <div class="info">
        <span18>C++</span18>
      </div>
      <div class="progress-line jquery">
        <span18></span18>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="bar">
      <div class="info">
        <span18>Java</span18>
      </div>
      <div class="progress-line python">
        <span18></span18>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="bar">
      <div class="info">
        <span18>Web Development (Front-End)</span18>
      </div>
      <div class="progress-line mysql">
        <span18></span18>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
            </div>
      </div>
      </div>
```

So there is nothing in my `animate` class as of right now because for some reason it would not work here, and `StackOverFlow` produces an error when I uncomment `var elementHeight = element.clientHeight;` as right now I have commented it out.

How would I trigger the animation of this element when it's in view? Any suggestions?

Please excuse the renaming of the classes, as I was trying something else

Comment: It's a bit unclear...do you want to animate all the elements when they are in view?

Comment: Yes thats exactly what I want to do, sorry for being so unclear

Comment: Your snippet tries to access an element with id box but I can't see it in your HTML. There is a way of the system telling you every time an element goes in or out of view without your needing to do lots of calculation on scrolling - intersectionObserver. That may help to simplify your code.

Answer (score 1):

What about something similar to this?

https://codepen.io/zvona/pen/ovDbk

```
    window.addEventListener("scroll", function() {
  onAppear.forEach(function(elem) {
    var vwTop = window.pageYOffset;
    var vwBottom = (window.pageYOffset + window.innerHeight);
    var elemTop = elem.offsetTop;
    var elemHeight = elem.offsetHeight;
    
    if (vwBottom > elemTop && ((vwTop - elemHeight) < elemTop)) {
     elem.classList.add("visible");
    } else {
      elem.classList.remove("visible");
    }
  });
}, false);
```

Comment: That makes more sense, but could you show an example with the code I sent above? I already tried several methods but there are problems I am facing with my code

Answer (score 0):

The code as it stands does not see when the elements have scrolled in/out of view as it's attempting to view an element, box, which is not there. So the animations run just once on each span18 element.

A clearer way of knowing when an element is in the viewport or not is to set up an intersectionObserver. This will trigger some code when an element goes in and out of view so you don't have to do the calculations.

I have also added a class 'animated' which gets added to a span18 element when it comes into view and gets removed when it goes out of view. If you don't do this you get the animation just the once, and if the element happens to be out of view on load the user never gets to see it.

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {

// THIS FUNCTION GETS CALLED WHENEVER A SPAN18 ELEMENT (OR ELEMENTS) COME INTO OR GO OUT OF VIEW
      function callback (observations, observer) {
        observations.forEach(observation => {
          if (observation.isIntersecting) { //IF IT'S IN VIEW
            observation.target.classList.add('animated');
          }
          else {
            observation.target.classList.remove('animated');
          }      
       });
     }
      
      // CREATE AN INTERSECTION OBSERVER
      let options = {
         root: null, //null means it will observe on the viewport
         rootMargin: '0px',
         threshold: 1.0 //1 means the whole element needs to be viewable before we animate it
      }

      let observer = new IntersectionObserver(callback, options);
      
      // NOW PUT THE OBSERVER ON EACH OF THE ELEMENTS WE WANT TO ANIMATE WHEN IT'S IN VIEW
      let spans = document.querySelectorAll('span18');
      for (let i=0; i< spans.length; i++) {
        observer.observe(spans[i]); 
      }
});
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:wght@200;300;400;500;600;700&display=swap');
*{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
}
body20{
  height: 100%;
  place-items: center;
  background: transparent;
}
::selection{
  color: #fff;
  background: black;
}
.skill-bars{
  padding: 25px 30px;
  width: 97%;
  background: #fff;
  box-shadow: 5px 5px 20px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  border-radius: 10px;
}
.skill-bars .bar{
  margin: 20px 0;
}
.skill-bars .bar:first-child{
  margin-top: 0px;
}
.skill-bars .bar .info{
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}
.skill-bars .bar .info span18{
  font-weight: 500;
  font-size: 17px;
  opacity: 0;
  animation: showText 0.5s 1s linear forwards;
}
.animate{ /* This is the animation class */

}
@keyframes showText {
  100%{
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
.skill-bars .bar .progress-line{
  height: 10px;
  width: 100%;
  background: #f0f0f0;
  position: relative;
  transform: scaleX(0);
  transform-origin: left;
  border-radius: 10px;
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.05),
              0 1px rgba(255,255,255,0.8);
                animation: animate 1s cubic-bezier(1,0,0.5,1) forwards; 

}
@keyframes animate {
  100%{
    transform: scaleX(1);
  }
}

.bar .progress-line span18{
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  border-radius: 10px;
  transform: scaleX(0);
  transform-origin: left;
  background: black;
}
/* SET THE ANIMATED CLASS TO GET IT TO ANIMATE */
.bar .progress-line span18.animated{
  animation: animate 1s 1s cubic-bezier(1,0,0.5,1) forwards;
}
.bar .progress-line.html span18{
  width: 84%;
}
.bar .progress-line.css span18{
  width: 76%;
}
.bar .progress-line.jquery span18{
  width: 91%;
}
.bar .progress-line.python span18{
  width: 59%;
}
.bar .progress-line.mysql span18{
  width: 70%;
}
/* ADDED ANIMATED HERE SO ANIMATES ONLY WHEN IN THE VIEWPORT */
.progress-line span18.animated::before{
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  top: -10px;
  right: 0;
  height: 0;
  width: 0;
  border: 7px solid transparent;
  border-bottom-width: 0px;
  border-right-width: 0px;
  border-top-color: #000;
  opacity: 0;
  animation: showText2 0.5s 1.5s linear forwards;
}
.progress-line span18.animated::after{
  position: absolute;
  top: -28px;
  right: 0;
  font-weight: 500;
  background: #000;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 1px 8px;
  font-size: 12px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  opacity: 0;
  animation: showText2 0.5s 1.5s linear forwards;
}
@keyframes showText2 {
  100%{
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
.progress-line.html span18::after{
  content: "84%";
}
.progress-line.css span18::after{
  content: "76%";
}
.progress-line.jquery span18::after{
  content: "91%";
}
.progress-line.python span18::after{
  content: "59%";
}
.progress-line.mysql span18::after{
  content: "70%";
}
```

```html
<div style="height: 100vh; width: 100vw; position: relative; background-color: cyan;"><div style="position: relative; top: 50vh; text-align: center;">SCROLL DOWN AND UP TO SEE THE ANIMATION EFFECTS</div></div>
<section>
        <div class="container" data-aos="fade-up">
      <div class="section-title">
        <h2>What I am Working On</h2>
        </div>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/picturealign.css"> 
      <div class="column1">
      <div class="row1">
  <div class="skill-bars">
    <div class="bar">
      <div class="info">
        <span18>Harvard CS50 Course</span18>
      </div>
      <div class="progress-line html">
        <span18></span18>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="bar">
      <div class="info">
        <span18>Youtube Channel (Java Tutorials)</span18>
      </div>
      <div class="progress-line css">
        <span18></span18>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="bar">
      <div class="info">
        <span18>C++</span18>
      </div>
      <div class="progress-line jquery">
        <span18></span18>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="bar">
      <div class="info">
        <span18>Java</span18>
      </div>
      <div class="progress-line python">
        <span18></span18>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="bar">
      <div class="info">
        <span18>Web Development (Front-End)</span18>
      </div>
      <div class="progress-line mysql">
        <span18></span18>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
            </div>
      </div>
      </div>
```